# How to create an Azure Subscription programatically on the Partner Center API of the CSP?

Tags: azure

i'm integrating my web app to Partner Center API and it is working great to Office 365, but for Azure i'm having some problems, the flow that i need to follow is "Create a customer > Create an Azure subscription for customer > Create a VM using the customer subscription" and all this is need to make in my app, i don't want to send my client to the azure portal to create the subscription, and i think that my client does't need to inform credit card information cause the billing is responsibility of the CSP reseller, am i right? So, i don't find any information about this on the CSP REST APIs and i'm not able to authenticate on the azure API cause i don't know how to create a azure subscription yet. On the CSP API i can create an azure subscription and i already do this, but this subscription seems to be not enough cause when i log on the azure portal and try to create a VM or any recourse, the portal send me to another window and ask me to complete my subscription profile with credit card and etc, i think that is not the right flow for a CSP Customer, and i want to make all this work in my app and never send my customer to real azure or any microsoft app portal, i need to resolve all the things on the API and the Azure subscription is a problem for now, it's possible to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For now it is not yet possible to programmatically create subscriptions.

As mentioned by the admin in this post:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/13117482-api-for-creating-accounts-and-subscriptions

Microsoft has planned to add this feature but there is no release date for now.

Comment: When I run the command to create a new subscription, the azure cli gives me a warn saying that "'create' is not in the 'az account' command group. See 'az account --help'".

az account create --offer-type "MS-AZR-0017P" --display-name "Dev Team Subscription" --enrollment-account-object-id "747ddfe5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" --owner-object-id "<userObjectId>","<servicePrincipalObjectId>"

Any idea?

Comment: @Fergara you most likely do not have the newest Azure Powershell Module installed. Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.6.0

As found on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: My bad. I forgot to "az extension add --name subscription". Thanks.